# Why are Information_schema queries so slow in Snowflake, is there any ways to speed them up?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently simple queries to INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, for example

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='HumanResources' and TABLE_NAME like '%EMP%'
```

Take considerable time.

I have heard of the workaround of doing something like:
`show tables`
And then use:
`select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))`

But I do not want to have to change my scripts. Is there a way to speed up those queries, and why are they so slow?

Comment: Have you tried a larger warehouse?  Also, if they are consistently very slow, I'd contact support and let them know.  There could be an issue with your account's deployment that they may not be aware of.

Comment: `"Take considerable time."` Could you use proper unit of time, for instance seconds and give us a comparison Information_schema vs Show tables? Are you using some kind of "chatty" application/ORM/ETL tool that ask for metadata every few seconds?

Comment: I am using the web interface And the python conector and queries take from 30s to almost 2min in the worst case scenario.

Comment: I ran this query (select * from "SNOWFLAKE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."TABLES";) using an XS WH and it took less than 2 seconds - so there definitely appears to be something wrong with your setup. Can you provide the Query profile for an instance of this query when it is taking  > 1 minute?

Comment: Sure @NickW. https://gist.github.com/orellabac/0e9fc9731e41472e381f0e3e957bf901#file-expensible_query-png you can see the profile there. The query is: select *
from information_schema.tables t
inner join information_schema.columns c on 
       c.table_schema = t.table_schema and c.table_name = t.table_name
where t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
       and lower(column_name) ='xxxx'
order by t.table_schema, 
       t.table_name;
and it takes close to 2 mins to complete.

I have cases where it has taken almost longer close to 4 mins, specially when using the snowflake connector for python.

Comment: Runs in 1-2s on my account. Think you should follow @MikeWalton 's advice and raise it directly with Snowflake Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the queries that were giving me problems were like this:

```sql
 select * from information_schema.tables t inner 
join information_schema.columns c on c.table_schema = t.table_schema and c.table_name = t.table_name 
where t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and
 lower(column_name) ='xxxx' 
 order by t.table_schema, t.table_name;
```

or

```
select * from information_schema.tables where upper(table_name) = 'some_table'
```

My information schema has 9045 rows.

My tests indicate that using the upper(table_name) or lower(table_name) added a lot of time to my queries.

So for example:

```sql
select * from information_schema.tables where upper(table_name) = 'some_table'
```

Takes 6.97s

and

```sql
select * from information_schema.tables where upper(table_name) = 'some_table'
```

Takes 1.84

Also we noticed that information_schema values are always uppercase so we are changing most of those values to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Most comments above relating this to the size of your warehouse are incorrect.
According to this Snowflake [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Long-running-Metadata-Operations) and I quote;

> All the queries which involve 'SHOW COMMANDS'  and
> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' views are referred to as metadata operations.
> They access specialized metadata services of Snowflake, metadata
> operations are not dependent on warehouse or customer data storage.

Another Snowflake [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/metadata-operations-throttling#:%7E:text=What%20are%20the%20Metadata%20Operations,warehouse%20or%20customer%20data%20storage.) also explains the concept and how to improve performance.

Comment: Sorry but the above statement/answer is incorrect as it applies to the particular scenario being discussed here. If you read to the end of the paragraph being quoted it states " if single query access several views of information schema and joins them then these serial operations will use the warehouse for joining after metadata read." As stated in the 1st answer, the SQL queries giving problems were joining tables and therefore use a warehouse - as can be seen if you run it (or something similar) and look at the query history where there will be a WH assigned to the query

Answer (score 0):

IT might be that you are applying functions to the columns itself. This forces the query engine to scan the whole table instead of a subset. If you can, apply functions on the static/value portion of the where clause instead of the column itself